# Can I travel to Italy with Bulgarian Visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel, italy, bulgaria

I'm an Indian passport holder with Bulgarian Visa. So is it possible to travel to Italy with a Bulgarian Visa?

Answer (score 2):

Bulgaria has not yet completed joining the Schengen area. Your Bulgarian visa is not a Schengen visa. You will need a Schengen visa to travel to Schengen area countries.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Michael says, if you haven't applied for any visas yet, you might want to get a Schengen visa. It will allow you to travel to the 26 Schengen states plus [Bulgaria](http://bulgarianembassy-london.org/consular-services/visas/) and a few other countries including [Croatia](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) and [Mexico](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico).

As a footnote, you might want to consider getting a longer travel insurance if your travel and financial records are good, you might be issued a longer validity Schengen visa, so more time to travel.