# Which countries in europe I can go with Bulgaria visa with multiple entry

Tags: europe, bulgaria

If I hold a Bulgaria visa with multiple entry, which other countries in Europe that I can visit?
Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I travel to Italy with Bulgarian Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130617/can-i-travel-to-italy-with-bulgarian-visa)

Comment: @Traveller I dont think it is an exact duplicate, as the answer might differ judging on [what you answered in another question a short while ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134051/can-i-enter-cyprus-using-a-united-kingdom-visa), which says Bulgarian multiple-entry visa holders are allowed into Cyprus.

Comment: I think the question might be to board in light of this information though. OP, do you have specific contries in mind to narrow the scope of the question?

Comment: @Traveller Clarification: "allowed into Cyprus" should be "allowed to visit Cyprus without a visa". Usual exceptions apply.

Comment: Not duplicate with this  Can I travel to Italy with Bulgarian Visa? , I have just wondered is there any country that I can go with Bulgaria visa

Comment: @B.Liu. I see some countries accept Bulgaria visa. For ex : Romania, Cyprus, Croatia. So I wondered is there any countries else :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reciprocal arrangements exist with Cyprus https://cyprusinuk.com/visa-information/, Romania https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040, and Croatia http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/

You’ll need a visa for all Schengen and all other non Schengen European countries, dependent on your citizenship.

Comment: Thank for youe information. As I know that some country accept Bulgaria visa. For ex : Romania, Cyprus, Croatia. So I wondered is there any countries else :D

Comment: Is there any other countries like countries that you mentioned above. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Nguyen Thanh Binh In essence, apart from the 3 you already know about, the answer is ‘none’ (depending on your citizenship).