# Can I enter Cyprus using a united kingdom visa?

Tags: cyprus

I have a UK visa that I have already used a few times to get into the UK. Can I enter Cyprus using this visa?

Answer (score 3):

No. If you are a visa national, a UK visa does not allow you to enter Cyprus. Holders of the following documents do not need a visa, as of 17 June 2014, to travel to Cyprus:

1. Schengen Visa rated for two or multiple entries.
2. Schengen Long Stay Visa.
3. Residence permit issued by a Schengen Country.
4. Romanian, Croatian and Bulgarian Visa, Valid for two or multiple entries.
5. Residence permit issued by Romania, Bulgaria and Croatia.

https://cyprusinuk.com/visa-information/